# getting error javascript error: video_js_1 is not defined

Tags: webdriver-io

I am trying to automated a player functions like play, pause etc, for which i installed package videojs running the code is showing below error
`javascript error: video_js_1 is not defined`

Below is my code
 `await browser.execute(async()=>{ await videojs.players.<video_id>.pause(); })`

have also imported
`import videojs from 'video.js';`

Trying to pause the video but getting error.